# Fedora 36/37 QT5 designer started to crash at startup

Tags: qt5

Suddenly qt5 designer stopped to start any more. I think last time I used was before latest update of Fedora 36.

```
saku@hamtpad tmp]$ designer-qt5 
Core has not been created
Core has not been created
Core has not been created
Muistialueen ylitys (luotiin core-tiedosto)  [memory overflow [core dumped)]
[saku@hamtpad tmp]$
```

- I removed ~/.designer folder, does not help.
- Upgraded to Fedora 37, does not help.
- Created a virtual machine with clean Fedora37 with qt5 designer ,** it works!**
- With my current system created a new user and tried with it, does not help.

According to two last tests I assume there is some kind of global setting that affects to startup for all users. On the other hand VM Fedora37 proves that there is no problem with clean machine.

It also seems to affect to QT5-creator. It starts but if I open the .ui file I did last open with qt5-designer the qt creator crashes, too. Removing the .ui file does not help.

What global setting could be the reason, and from where to find them for cleanup?